# Issue on batch working on seven but not on xp

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

```
@echo off
echo user abc> ftpcmd.dat
echo xxxx>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd /www/ping_vm/>> ftpcmd.dat
echo lcd C:\PING_VM>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put vm.txt>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.abcxxx.com
del ftpcmd.dat
pause
```

On windows seven, this works fine.
When I try this on XP, I get this:

```
230-User bizbetti has group access to:  users
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
ftp> bin
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
ftp> cd /www/ping_vm/
250 OK. Current directory is /www/ping_vm
ftp> lcd C:\PING_VM
Dossier local maintenant C:\PING_VM.
ftp> put vm.txt
vm.txt: Fichier introuvable
ftp> quit
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
```

I don't understand why the file is not uploaded at all on the XP pc.

Do you have any ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTP `PUT` command doesn't support a path as far as I know.

You normally use the `LCD` command to change the local working directory and then use the filename alone.

You are also using unix separators instead of Windows as in `C:\PING_VM\vm.txt`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I modified the code with the right syntaxs. I have this now : 'vm.txt: Fichier introuvable', meaning the file is not found.

Comment: I found finally. It was an issue with the extension of the file... I had vm.txt.txt in fact... Thanks.